# What is a "jobset" in the parlance of the Hydra continuous integration tool?

Tags: nix, nix-hydra

I found definitions (see below) and how they are usually used (i.e., a Hydra jobset is tracking a git branch) but I still couldn't figure out what they are in the general sense. Maybe if you could explain it laymen's terms with specific examples?

- [**Eelco Dolstra, Eelco Visser: "*Hydra: A Declarative Approach to Continuous Integration*"**](https://edolstra.github.io/pubs/hydra-scp-submitted.pdf)

  > a specification of the location of a Nix expression, along with possible values for the function arguments of the jobs defined by the Nix expression.
- [NixOS Wiki: "*Hydra*"](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Hydra)

  > #### Job Set
  >
  > A list of jobs which will be run. Often a Jobset fits to a certain branch (master, staging, stable). A jobset is defined by its inputs and will trigger if these inputs change, e.g. like a new commit onto a branch is added. Job sets may depend on each other
- [Hydra User's Guide](http://ondoc.logand.com/d/5081/pdf)

  > #### 3.2 Job Sets
  >
  > A project can consist of multiple job sets (hereafter jobsets), separate tasks that can be built separately, but may depend on each other (without cyclic dependencies, of course).

My question may seem pointless after listing all these definitions, but here's an examle to demonstrate my confusion: I looked at the project listing at https://hydra.nixos.org/ and I was under the impression that a project is a channel, and jobsets are the branches in a repo. (I know, there is no mention of "channel" in there, and on the channel page it even says that ["*Nix channels are not supported by this Hydra server.*"](https://hydra.nixos.org/project/flakes/channel/latest) :)
I could fool myself with that when looking at the [Hydra project](https://hydra.nixos.org/project/hydra) but this argument fell apart when I clicked on the [flakes one](https://hydra.nixos.org/project/flakes) (that is, couldn't find a supporting github repo, but generally the jobset names didn't feel like branch names).

Also, in the Dolstra/Visser paper, Hydra was set up using SVN; I don't know if SVN even uses branches (mostly because the paper didn't mention them) but this does prove that Hydra can be set up with VCS/SCM other than git where the underlying concepts can be fundamentally different. Again, I could easily be wrong.

Comment: A jobset specifies, in effect, _a set of expressions_ to be evaluated against the contents of a repo. Compare the -small channels to the big ones; the only difference is the size of the jobset that needs to complete successfully before promotion.

Comment: Not _everything_ that could possibly be built from a channel is actually built by Hydra (remember that nixpkgs contains things like `muslPkgs`, which itself contains _all of nixpkgs_, but compiled against musl libc instead of glibc; similarly, if we're looking at the total addressible space, it includes outdated packages like `python38Packages` that no longer have binaries built by default -- since the current default is 3.9 -- but are still available for folks who actually need them to use). The subset that _is_ built by Hydra is defined by the jobsets.

Comment: BTW, what a svn user calls a branch is different from what git calls a branch. Effectively, a SVN repository is a single enormous tree of which clients are expected to check out only a subset, so in SVN you might have `/projects/foobar/trunk` and `/projects/foobar/branches/1.2.x` be two parts of that overarching tree, so creating a 1.3.x branch off of trunk looks like `svn cp https://svn.example.com/projects/foo/trunk https://svn.example.com/projects/foo/branches/1.3.x`, and tagging 1.3.1 might be `svn cp "$root/projects/foo/branches/1.3.x" "$root/projects/foo/tags/1.3.1"`

Comment: ...so in the svn world, the revision control system is just providing a big versioned filesystem, and "branches" and "tags" are user-provided semantics layered on top. The above (re: svn details) is just an aside, though; no particular relevance to the question here.

Comment: (aside: I'm in the minority that thinks the world would have been better off if git had lost the war for DSCM supremacy; if the technical community had taken just a few more years to coalesce around a single version control system, that system might have ended up being Mercurial or Bazaar, and we wouldn't have had abominations like destructive force-push workflows. That didn't happen, because git was the first to have good performance at scale, and by the time the others caught up it was too late)

Comment: What a gem: "**_a set of expressions to be evaluated against the contents of a repo_"** - thank you! The 2nd sentence is pretty dense so that will need more time to decipher that. Also enjoyed the SVN and general SCM asides; if you have a post about this topic, I would love to read it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the best definition in [the flox documentation](https://beta.floxdev.com/docs/tour/tour-1/#view-available-packages):

> Within channels, ***jobsets** allow flox to build packages against multiple versions of dependencies simultaneously*.

<sup>flox is a framework built around the Nix eco-system to use Nix without having to install it; it seamlessly relays Nix commands to a remote Nix store and Hydra build farm as if they were issued on the local machine, and thus one would consistently get the same results everywhere where flox is installed.</sup>

If I understand this correctly,

- the `stable` jobset would then specify as inputs the latest stable releases of all the dependencies of the channel's packages (e.g., from their release branch)
- `staging` / `unstable` would take the latest revision of a development branch (e.g., `master` / `main`) of the dependencies (a.k.a., bleeding edge)
- and so on.

<sup>Note to self: jobset specification applies to **every package** in a channel.</sup>

---

Some lingering questions if the above is correct:

- **What does a jobset specification look like?** For example, `stable` takes the latest commits (i.e. `HEAD`) of release branches, whereas `staging`/`unstable` would do the same but for `master`/`main` (or other development) branches?

Comment: Review from anyone with experience in this field would be highly appreciated. Wouldn't want to promote inaccurate ideas.